# Match a text value in a column and perform a function on values in another column that match

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Using Google Sheets I'm attempting to perform a match of values in a particular column and then based on that column execute a function(`SUM`) on matching values in a different column.

I've tried `LOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP` but those are throwing errors, presumably because they are expecting to only return a single value in a given range and not perform the `SUM` that I am requiring.

`=LOOKUP("[sometext]*", A2:A25, SUM(H2:H25))`

Ideally, what I would like to happen is to search the range A2:A25, find any rows that match "sometext*", e.g. "sometext1", "sometext2", "sometext3" etc. and then move over to second range and sum the values in the matched rows, e.g. "1", "2", "3" and return "6".

Comment: Cannot do that for security reasons. Easy to recreate yourself. 2 Columns, A & B. Values for first 5 rows of A) "something1", "something2", "something3", "nothing1", "nothing2". Values for first 5 rows of B) "1", "2", "3", "4", "5". Now just locate all values in column A that match "something*" and sum the values in column B for those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A25, "sometext"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A25, "\D+", )*1, )))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A25, "sometext"), B2:B25, )))
```

[image: r updated]

Comment: Close, this is at least grabbing the values from Column A correctly, but it looks like what it is doing is looking at the number at the end of the strung and summing them? I just need to sum values for those matches that are stored in column B.

Comment: @super_cool_display_name `...looking at the number at the end of the strung and summing them?` - yes. `I just need to sum values for those matches that are stored in column B` - what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: your spreadsheet has no values in Column B. I need to sum the values that are in column B based on the matched values in column A. For example: https://imgur.com/MtCGUjV the sum result should be 6(B1+B2+B4).